# how can we add text to a svg circle in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to put text inside circle which is created by d3js, how can I do that?

```
const svg = d3.select("#circle").append("svg").attr("width", 300).attr("height", 300)
const text = ['Team']
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 100)
  .attr('cy', 75)
  .attr('r', 35)
  .attr('stroke', '#41778D')
  .attr('stroke-width', 5)
  .attr('fill', '#ffffff');

svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 100)
  .attr('cy', 75)
  .attr('r', 27)
  .attr('stroke', '#41778D')
  .attr('fill', '#ffffff');
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to appending your circles:

```
svg.append('text')
  .text(text[0])
  .attr('y', 100)
  .attr('x', 75)
```

You'll need to adjust based on the alignment and anchoring/